# connect to mssql in Nestjs with Typeorm, but Nest can't resolve dependencies of the EmployeeRepository

Tags: sql-server, typescript, nestjs, typeorm

I'm connect mssql in Nestjs with Typeorm and get error `Nest can't resolve dependencies of the EmployeeRepository`

my app.module.ts file:

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AppController } from './app.controller';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import config from '../ormconfig';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { EmployeesModule } from './employees/employees.module';
@Module({
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forRoot({ ...config, autoLoadEntities: true }),
    EmployeesModule,
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

ormconfig.ts file:

```
const config: SqlServerConnectionOptions = {
  type: 'mssql',
  host: 'localhost',
  port: 1433,
  username: 'sa',
  password: 'sa',
  database: 'db1',
  synchronize: false,
};

export default config;
```

employees.module.ts file:

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { Employee } from './employee.entity';
import { EmployeesController } from './employees.controller';
import { EmployeesService } from './employees.service';
@Module({
  imports: [TypeOrmModule.forFeature([Employee])],
  providers: [EmployeesService],
  controllers: [EmployeesController],
})
export class EmployeesModule {}
```

employees.service.ts file:

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { InjectRepository } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { Repository } from 'typeorm';
import { Employee } from './employee.entity';

@Injectable()
export class EmployeesService {
  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(Employee)
    private employeesRepository: Repository<Employee>,
  ) {}

  findAll(): Promise<Employee[]> {
    return this.employeesRepository.find();
  }
}
```

employee.entity.ts file:

```
import {
  Entity,
  PrimaryGeneratedColumn,
  Column,
  BaseEntity,
} from 'typeorm';

@Entity('Employees')
export class Employee extends BaseEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn({ type: 'int' })
  EmployeeID!: number;

  @Column({ type: 'nvarchar', length: 50 })
  FirstName!: string;

  @Column({ type: 'nvarchar', length: 50 })
  LastName!: string;
...
}
```

the employees.controller.ts file is doing nothing only barebone created by CLI. There is a table called `Employees` in db1 from mssql. I just cannot figure out why this's happening. I even tried deleting dist and node_modules, but no luck.

main parts of my package.json

```
    "scripts": {
    "prebuild": "rimraf dist",
    "build": "nest build",
    "format": "prettier --write \"src/**/*.ts\" \"test/**/*.ts\"",
    "start": "nest start",
    "start:dev": "nest start --watch",
    "start:debug": "nest start --debug --watch",
    "start:prod": "node dist/main",
    "lint": "eslint \"{src,apps,libs,test}/**/*.ts\" --fix",
    "test": "jest",
    "test:watch": "jest --watch",
    "test:cov": "jest --coverage",
    "test:debug": "node --inspect-brk -r tsconfig-paths/register -r ts-node/register node_modules/.bin/jest --runInBand",
    "test:e2e": "jest --config ./test/jest-e2e.json"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@nestjs/common": "^7.6.15",
    "@nestjs/core": "^7.6.15",
    "@nestjs/platform-express": "^7.6.15",
    "@nestjs/typeorm": "^7.1.5",
    "mssql": "^7.1.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
    "rimraf": "^3.0.2",
    "rxjs": "^6.6.6",
    "typeorm": "^0.2.34"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nestjs/cli": "^7.6.0",
    "@nestjs/schematics": "^7.3.0",
    "@nestjs/testing": "^7.6.15",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.11",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.22",
    "@types/node": "^14.14.36",
    "@types/supertest": "^2.0.10",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.19.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.19.0",
    "eslint": "^7.22.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.3.1",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "prettier": "^2.2.1",
    "supertest": "^6.1.3",
    "ts-jest": "^26.5.4",
    "ts-loader": "^8.0.18",
    "ts-node": "^9.1.1",
    "tsconfig-paths": "^3.9.0",
    "typescript": "^4.2.3"
  },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest adding the entities path oin your config so it can find files :

```
  type: 'mssql',
  host: 'localhost',
  port: 1433,
  username: 'sa',
  password: 'sa',
  database: 'db1',
  entities: ["dist/**/*.entity{.ts,.js}"],
  synchronize: false,
};
```

doc : https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/database#repository-pattern

Comment: Hi, I tried but got the same error. I even add autoLoadEntities: true as shown in my app.module file which is inspired by Nestjs exmple code.

Comment: sorry can't reproduce your issue, just tried the same and eveything got ok (even without entities option)... Are you libs up-to-date ?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I add package.json in the question above. I started this project a week ago. All packages should be alright.

Comment: you r correct, I start it from scratch. it works. I must have done something stupid which I still do not know the cause of the error. Thanks anyway!